# SSRS Subscription - Maximum Request Length Exceeded Error

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

I am trying to create a subscription for an SSRS report in Report Manager on the report server.

When I click **OK** or try to change the time, I immediately get an error message:

> Maximum request length exceeded.

When I **Google** for the error, the answers all relate to the size of the RDL report file being over **4 meg**. My report is only **384k** and the resulting **Excel** file is only **119k**.

Is there anything else I can change to make this work?

I have also noticed that when I do get the error, my current Internet Explorer history is wiped out. I cannot go **BACK** after getting the error. I get the same error with Chrome except that the history doesn't get wiped out.

I had a working subscription but I deleted to try with a newly deployed version of the report.

[image]

**History wiped out?**

Comment: Did you try the solution that is offered everywhere (modify web.config and increase the MaxRequestLength)?

Comment: Does your report have parameters that have a list of possible values returned by a dataset? I have seen something similar when the list of values was extremely long - it prevented the user from creating a subscription.

Comment: @ChrisLätta - Unfortunately, that would take months to accomplish where I work (even in DEV). I don't think I could even sell it since the file size doesn't seem to be an issue.

Comment: @Nathan - it does have a couple of parameters that do have a hundred or so values but I use the same parameters in other reports. The report subscription was actually working but wouldn't let me add a user to the **TO** list.